# creating new line in txt file

Tags: c#, newline

I'm using this code for insert new line,
it works in label,

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\hello\Desktop\hello.txt", "\n"+"hello"+"\n"+"hello \n");
```

but it doesn't work in txt file

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2):

I should use Environment.NewLine instead of \n

Comment: Yes you should, maybe add an example as well